# get posts based on category and post meta

Tags: get-posts, date-time, post-meta

I am coding a Live Show box for a radio website to show who is on air and who is up next. I've been using the get_post function to retrieve posts based on the category (in this case the day of the week), and whether the show has yet to reach its End Time (custom field) in order to display the show which should be live on air now.

However, it's had a turn and will work sometimes, and will show the wrong show title at others. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Code is below and visit http://livewire1350.com to see it in action.

EDIT: I have modified the code based on @CharlesClarkson 's comments but there is still a problem occurring. For debugging purposes I set the code to show the whole entire list of posts in ascending order of time but between 0:00 and 9:00, it begins to list 22:30 descending to 18:00 before resuming at 9:00 in ascending fashion up until 17:00 (like below). Any ideas why this could be happening?

LIVE: 9:29

0:00

LIVE: 9:29

22:30

LIVE: 9:29

21:00

LIVE: 9:29

19:30

LIVE: 9:29

18:00

LIVE: 9:29

9:00

LIVE: 9:29

10:30

LIVE: 9:29

12:00

LIVE: 9:29

12:30

LIVE: 9:29

14:00

LIVE: 9:29

15:30

LIVE: 9:29

17:00

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$now  = time();
$time = date( 'G:i');
$day_of_the_week = date( 'w', $now );
//                                    S   M   T   W   T   F   S
$day_of_the_week_categories = array( 17, 18, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 );
$day_of_the_week = date( 'w' );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => $day_of_the_week_categories[ $day_of_the_week ],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Start_Time',
            'type'    => 'TIME',
        )
    )
   )
);
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
<div class="liveshow">
    <div id="livebanner">

    <div id="showwrap">
    <div id="showdetails">
        <div id="onair">
            <h3>LIVE: <?php echo $time ?></h3><p class="showname"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php $short_title = substr(the_title('','',FALSE),0,18);
                                                echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Start_Time', true );

                                             ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Any idea under what specific conditions it fails? What is the relationship of the "wrong title" to what should be the correct title?

Comment: And also, please, format and indent your code so it is easy for anyone to follow the logic. I have to say that, right now, the appeal to read this code is almost zero.

Comment: This code is incomplete. You never close most of the `<div>s` that you open in the while loop and the `if` conditional never ends. It gets to `else:` statement, but the `endif;` is missing.

Comment: Is the wrong title appearing when the page is loaded around midnight on the server?

Comment: @barsofilo - sorry I have tried to reformat it to make it easier for you

Comment: @CharlesClarkson - Yes when it gets to midnight the wrong title appears until roughly 10am-ish. I also realised I hadn't included all the code so have updated it with the closed divs and the endif comes after the else.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Problems:

- A change in the time zone could between `'End_Time'` and `date( 'G:i' )`.
- A change in the time between calling `date( 'G:i' )` and `date( 'w' )`.
- Repeated use of the `date( 'w' )` function.
- A meta query logic problem.

Any of these could be the culprit.

**The time zone problem**

If the time set in the `'End_Time'` custom value is a different time zone from the web server, you might need to change `date( 'G:i' )` to adjust that time zone change. I do not know all the ramifications of using this call:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

You should probably do some testing near midnight (server time) to see what `date( 'G:i' )`and `date( 'w' )` are returning and compare them with typical `'End_Time'` custom values from posts.

---

**The `date( 'w' )` function**

You check it repeatedly, but what happens near midnight on the server?

```
     if ( date( 'w' ) == 0 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 1 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 2 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 3 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 4 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 5 ) {
else if ( date( 'w' ) == 6 ) {
```

Near midnight the value in date( 'w' ) could change. If it does, there is a chance that `$args` is either unset or set to a value with the wrong category.

It would be better to check `date( 'w' )` only one time:

```
$day_of_the_week = date( 'w' );

     if ( $day_of_the_week == 0 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 1 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 2 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 3 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 4 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 5 ) {
else if ( $day_of_the_week == 6 ) {
```

You really do not need all the `if else if` stuff. Since you are only changing the `'cat'` argument, this should do the same thing without all that typing.

```
$time = date( 'G:i' );
//                                    S   M   T   W   T   F   S
$day_of_the_week_categories = array( 17, 18, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 );
$day_of_the_week = date( 'w' );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => $day_of_the_week_categories[ $day_of_the_week ],
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'End_Time',
            'value'   => $time,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type'    => 'TIME',
        ),
    ),
);
```

---

**Change in the time between calling `date( 'G:i' )` and `date( 'w' )`**

Close to midnight (server time) the call to `date( 'G:i' )` might occur on Tuesday and the call to `date( 'w' )` might occur on Wednesday. This might be fixed by changing the code above to this:

```
$now  = time();
$time = date( 'G:i', $now );
$day_of_the_week = date( 'w', $now );
```

The PHP `date()` function gets the time from the PHP `time()` function. By doing all time calculations off a single call to `time()`, `$time` and `$day_of_the_week` should always refer to the same time and day.

---

**A meta query logic problem.**

This problem is harder to diagnose without working directly on the web site and testing the posts there. It is very important that all date and time functions used to calculate `'End_Time'` are also used to calculate `$time` and `$day_of_the_week`. Similar midnight problems may arise when calculating `'End_Time'`.

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid. It is weird as I've tested the server date() values against the 'End_Time" values of the posts and there's nothing suspicious, yet it doesn't order them by the time...

Also checked it against a local server which seems to work fine, yet the live site still has problems despite the coding being the same.